# docker command doesn't identify the env variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, containers, docker-build

I am new to docker and nx world. in the project.json target file `

```
"docker-build": {
      "dependsOn": ["build"],
      "command": "docker build -f <path>/Dockerfile . -t <image>:$SOME_VARIABLE"

},
```

when I execute nx docker-build command in the terminal I get the error "invalid argument ":$SOME_VARIABLE" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format"

Please note that before running the nx commands, I exported a value for the env variable. I tried several ways, but I wonder if this is related to the string syntax in the "command". Please share your knowledge on this. Thank you.

Comment: What tool is interpreting this JSON file?  It seems like that tool isn't running a shell or otherwise expanding the environment variables; this doesn't seem like it's a Docker problem _per se_.